# TypeScript interface is not working as expected, it doesn't throw any "warning" when provided type is wrong

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, ts-loader

TypeScript interface doesn't work as expected with '*.vue' files. it doesn't throw any "warning" when provided type is bad. Example form vue.js file:

```
<script lang="ts">

interface Test {
   w: string;
   h: number;
}

// This part of code doesn't work. 
// It doesn't show any message about 
// type incompatibility 
//(propert h must have "number" type).

let myVar: Test = {
    w: "10",
    h: "26",
};

//At the same time this code works correctly in '.ts' files.

</script>
```

How to fix it?

My devDependencies info:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/velocity-animate": "^1.2.30",
    "@types/vue-resource": "^0.9.31",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "*",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "normalize.css": "*",
    "pug": "*",
    "ts-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "vue": "*",
    "vue-resource": "*",
    "vue-router": "*"
  },
```

Comment: This would be an issue on TS Language Service. I would suggest you to open an issue at vscode (assuming you are using vscode).

Comment: if you are using vscode try associating vue files to ts files. It should stop complaining then. https://scottaddie.com/2016/04/10/file-to-language-associations-in-visual-studio-code/